# i want to add hello world in the same line

Tags: php, mysql, database

one way is to use `file()` function. In returns an array of the contents of that particular file per line. From there, you can manipulate the array and append that value on that specific line. Consider this example:

```
// Sample file content (original)
// line 1
// line 2
// line 3
// line 4
// line 5
// line 6


$replacement = "Hello World";
$specific_line = 3; // sample value should be printed on this line
$contents = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if($specific_line > sizeof($contents)) {
    $specific_line = sizeof($contents) + 1;
}
array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, 0, array($replacement)); // arrays start at zero index
$contents = implode("\n", $contents);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $contents);


// Sample output is this
// line 1
// line 2
// Hello World
// line 3
// line 4
// line 5
// line 6


// but  Sample output should be
// line 1
// line 2
// line 3 Hello World
// line 4
// line 5
// line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, 0, array($replacement));
```

Replace this one with

```
array_splice($contents, $specific_line-1, 1, array($contents[$specific_line-1].$replacement)); // arrays start at zero index
```

[Array Splice Detail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)